# Importing a file in Javascript using Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, qt-creator, qml

how do I import a file in Javascript on Ubuntu? Here is my current code:

TextFile.js

```
var file = null;
function createFile()
{
    file = new StreamReader();
    file.open("~//home//chris//LcdDisplayFile//qml//file.txt");
}

function readLine()
{
    var str = file.readLine();
    return str;
}
```

For some reason it cannot find the file. I am new to both jscript and ubuntu.
Error:

> file:///home/chris/LcdDisplayFile/qml/TextFile.js:10: TypeError: Result of expression 'file' [null] is not an object.

Comment: You are trying to read file stream in JavaScript?! Dead end my friend... JavaScript doesn't work with files/IO streams.

Comment: @Cipi that is not really true at all. There are various ways of running JavaScript as a "server-side" component (that is, from a command line), and most of those provide one way or another of getting at the file system and other resources. Used in that way, JavaScript is basically just another programming language.  The "sandboxing" of JavaScript in web browsers is imposed by the browser and not an intrinsic aspect of the language.

Answer (score 1):

`~` already points to `/home/chris/`. Also, why did you use a double `//`?<sup>[1]</sup> These slashes have no special meaning inside a string.

<sup>[1]</sup>Windows directories are separated by a backslash (`\`), which have a special meaning in JavaScript strings (escape character), hence `\\`. Normal slashes do not have to be escaped, and can be safely written as `/` (One exception: Regular expressions)

Comment: Hang on, JScript (windows) + Ubuntu? Are you trying to access a Linux filesystem through Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using a non-standard server-side extension of JavaScript such as NodeJS ( http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.9/api/fs.html#fs.open ), file I/O is not part of the standard set of objects. JavaScript in the browser does not support file I/O.

At any rate, the main problem here is, what and where is the StreamReader object. If the given JavaScript environment provides it, then the object should not be a null.

Comment: Rhino absolutely supports file I/O in that it provides seamless (well, almost seamless; direct anyway) access to *all* of the Java standard libraries, including the `java.io` package.

Comment: The plot thickens. The JavaScript in QT Creator is actually a variant of JavaScript embedded in the QML interface spec language. It some ways, it is an extension of JavaScript (extended with a suite of QML objects). In other ways, it is a restriction (immutable global). http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdeclarativejavascript.html In any case, I have not found any indication that this variant of JavaScript is server-side or provides stream I/O. It does however provide a function Qt.include to import another JavaScript file. So presumably one can access JSON-encoded data.

Comment: It also supports AJAX-like loading into the QML but, alas, no local file I/O thus far. http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-loader.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't know anything about QML, I assume it supports IO and provides it own class for reading streams and that you are using it correctly. Either way your file path is invalid... shouldn't it just be:

```
var path = '~/LcdDisplayFile/qml/file.txt'
```

or

```
var path = '/home/chris/LcdDisplayFile/qml/file.txt'
```

Also keep in mine Linux file paths are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some documentation regarding using javascript with QML. I hope this helps:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qtqml-javascript-imports.html